# Are there any drawbacks to using the Gradle wrapper as suggested when creating an IntelliJ project?

Tags: gradle

I have never used the gradle wrapper, but IntelliJ Documentation recommends it.  Are there any drawbacks to using it?

In particular, if I use 'too new' a version,  will I have any trouble porting to older OSs?

Comment: OP clearly stated ‘in particular and cited IntelliJ context’. If you use those products together, you will see that there is a push by JetBrains in the direction of using the wrapper, with no explaination of why. Totally valid question.  I will update wording with those specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrapper makes your projects more self contained and build-predictable.  You can set the version to whatever you want, so 'too new' a version is not an issue.  The wrapper is also cross platform.

The main upside is that you can set the version in your build file, and anyone pulling down the code will build off of your specified Gradle version, regardless of what they have installed on their machine, or even not installed at all.

The downsides are:

- Uses more drive space.
- Harder to change the Gradle version on multiple projects at once, unless you have a common defined version somewhere, and that creates a dependency between projects.  If you have many projects and upgrade gradle version to the latest and greatest, each will have to download it.  Then again, the Gradle files to install will be cached locally, so that will speed things up.

Now for the opinion part...

I find that unless I need to **lock a project to a specific Gradle version** for compatibility, or have many **others building a project that may be using different Gradle versions**, I am happy linking to a local version from the IJ project, and not using the wrapper.  That way I can change the version for all my project’s modules in one place.